# Drag and Drop tile in TileMap

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap

I am new to using TileMaps so I am not sure if this is possible.
How can I add a Drag & Drop option for my TileMap?

I have no problem identifying a click on a tile but don't know how to go about dragging.
I want to be able to drag it to another place on the tile grid and snap into place.

I have tried to use DragHandler but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail about what it is you want to drag, and what it is you want to receive the drop? Do you need to support multiple different draggables or different drop targets?

Comment: @DMGregory I am trying to drag some adjacent ties together from one place in a Tilemap to somewhere else. I figured that once I can drag one I can "attach" the others to drag together by applying the movement to all the tiles.